# Resetting xtics ytics gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way to reset or to use the default settings for xtics (or ytics) after I've already used a custom setting?

I need something like that:

```
set ytics 0.005 nomirror
set y2tics 5 nomirror
plot 'dummy' u 1:2 axes x1y1, dummy2 u 1:2 axes x1y2

##Another plot with "normal" axes
set ytics default (this command doesn't exist but this is what I need)
set y2tics default
plot 'dummy3' u 1:2
```

So if that command would actually exist, that would solve my problem because what I have now is that the second plot is using, of course, the ytics defined for the previous one. And I don't want to use the *reset* option because I don't want to define everything again in my script.

Thank you very much!

Comment: thx I will check!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put `reset` before your second plot. But it will reset everything and might be an overkill for you.

You can also use `set ytics auto`. It might be better.

Best,

Comment: Also, if you've changed the tics format, you can reset to the default format specifier: `set xtics format "%h"` or `set xtics format "$%h$"` for LaTeX-type terminals

Answer (score 0):

From gnuplot help:

> The defaults are `border mirror norotate` for tics on the x and y axes, and
>    `border nomirror norotate` for tics on the x2 and y2 axes.

So, your commands should be:

```
set ytics border mirror norotate autofreq
set y2tics border nomirror norotate autofreq
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
unset ytics
```

from http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node295.html

```
The tics may be turned off with the unset xtics command
```